# Pandas Dataframes, Join two rows into one according to column name

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm working on the John Hopkins covid19 data and I'm having some problems with isos and plotly.chloropleth, but so what I want to do is add the two Congo rows together into one row for said dataset, namely:

[image]

and

[image]

That is, add the values together for all the dates and I'll keep just 'Congo' as one country. How would I go about doing that? Any help appreciated.

Also does anyone know why Greenland isn't in that dataset or am I just blind?

Comment: Please do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888) If you need assistance formatting a small sample of your DataFrame as a copyable piece of code for SO see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: Without access to the data it is difficult to tell how countries are organised and what standard rules may or may not be acceptable to extract and group Country/Regions together. In addition, while you may eventually want to plot your results with plotly. This question does not currently appear to be _about_ plotting, but rather the DataFrame transformation which is why I have removed the plotly tag.

Comment: Why join the two Congo rows? You know they are two different countries. And I'm not sure which file you are looking at or which data, but when I look, I find Greenland, it's filed as a part of Denmark.

Comment: I realised that after. You're an absolute gentleman, creanion. I am blind it seems, very.

Comment: Hahaha! - Is your question answered @John?

Comment: Great, done and dusted.. For now. Good luck :)